# How do I create a dynamic selection on a linq query with an Expression

Tags: c#, linq

assume I have a couple classes like such:

```
public class QueryDetail
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Expression<Func<MyObject, object>> IdToMapOn { get; set; }
}

public class MyObject
{
  public string FooId { get; set; }
  public string BarId { get; set; }
}
```

How do I filter the following query:

```
(f, l) => 
{ 
  return f.RecordCollection.Select(l.IdToMapOn); // how do I use that expression?
}
```

- where `f.RecordCollection` is an `IEnumerable` of type `MyObject`
- and `l` is a `QueryDetail`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An expression needs to be compiled. See [Expression Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
(f, l) => 
{ 
    var compiled = l.IdToMapOn.Compile();
    return f.RecordCollection.Select(compiled.Invoke);
}
```

Comment: If the query is always going to be a plain LINQ-to-Objects query, it may be better to simply declare the filter as a `Func<MyObject,object>` instead of an expression, so that it can be used directly.